# Rails: gmaps4rails - Start the map location atlocation within the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maps

I dont think there is need for me to post specific code from my application.
In simple terms I have a db table with name,address,longitude,latitude,gmaps.
Each record stores a location. Okay. When I load the page, the google maps just starts off in the middle of the atlantic ocean, I was wondering is there a way for it to start off on one of my locations that I already have in my table?

Answer (score 0):

Hey when you pass a record to the view you can use it to center the map.

```
<%= gmaps({
      "map_options" => { "auto_adjust" => false, "center_longitude" => @record.long, "center_latitude" => @record.lat, "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 5 },
      "markers"     => {"data" => @json }
    })
%>
```

When you try this, make sure you have set `auto_adjust` to `false`.